# How to record prices for the product sales?

Tags: mysql, database-design

I'm building a database for daily sales report. For example:

29/01/2021 -> 50 apples were sold
30/01/2021 -> 46 apples were sold

I have these tables:

`products`

- id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
- name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
- price FLOAT NOT NULL
- deleted_at DATETIME NULL,
- Other stuff

`sales`

- saledate DATE,
- product_id INT,
- quantity INT,
- PRIMARY KEY (saledate, product_id),
- FOREIGN KEY (product_id) REFERENCES products(id),

It is working. But now I have to record the price of the product when it was sold. The problem is that the product's price can be changed during the day for example:

29/01/2021 -> 43 apples were sold (Apple price: 1$)
29/01/2021 -> 7 apples were sold (Apple price: 0.90$)
30/01/2021 -> 46 apples were sold (Apple price: 1.10$)

as you can see, on **29/01/2021** **we sold 43 apples to 1$ and 7 apples to 0.90$** because the price of  apples has changed. I thought to add a column to `sales` table: `price FLOAT NOT NULL` but then how can I to have multiple prices associated to a specific saledate?

In essence, how to change the `sales` table to get output like in the example above? I thought to make `price` column primary key: `PRIMARY KEY (saledate, product_id, price)` but honestly I don't know if it is a clean solution and if it has a bad impact on performance. Currently the query to insert a new sale is:

```
INSERT INTO sales (saledate, product_id, quantity) VALUES(date_value, product_id_value, quantity_value)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE quantity = quantity + quantity_value
```

Thank you in advance.

PS: Sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you really should do (and is how a lot of similar type systems architect their schema) is have two normalized tables that store sales information.

One table is the `SalesHeader` (or sometimes just called `SalesOrder`) and the other table is the `SalesLine`. `SalesHeader` has a **one-to-many foreign key relationship** to `SalesLine` on the `OrderId`.

The `SalesHeader` stores basic information like `OrderId` (as the **primary key**) and `SaleDate`, where the `SalesLine` table has a new record for each `ProductId` with `Quantity` and `Price` columns, and its own **primary key** column called `LineId`.

This allows you the flexibility to have the same product sold on the same date at different prices, or even multiple products on the same date at different prices, and even batch different orders up (if you wanted). You can adjust the `SalesHeader` and `SalesLine` tables as what's more relevant to your use case, but that's the general solution. (Also please don't mind that I use PascalCasing when naming my obejcts. :)

Comment: The way I was taught was to think of a single invoice as two different things. One table record is created for the whole invoice (Customer, date) and another record in a different table is for each line item bought (ItemID, Quantity, Price)

Comment: @JohnHerbert Right, that's essentially what I'm saying. Invoices, Orders, Purchases, etc all generally follow the same pattern. A header table and a lines table. Header table stores the high level commonality fields such as `Customer` and `Date` and the lines fields store the individual items belonging to a particular header, such as the `ItemName`, `ItemId`, `Price` etc. The key between the two tables is usually the ID from the header table, e.g. `OrderId`.

Comment: First of all thank you for the reply. if I understand correctly, I should to have these tables:

```SalesHeader: OrderId (PK, autoincrement), saleDate (DATE)```
```SalesLine: LineId, ProductId, Quantity, Price```

every time a product is sold, I should to add a new line to SalesHeader with the date, and a new line to SalesLine with infos. I have a question: every time I sell a product (for example "Apples") in the same date, in the SalesLine table should I to increment the quantity (of "Apples") or just to add a new line?

Comment: Sorry for another question (but the answer to this question could to answer to previous question) Why should I to create two tables instead of a single table like the below answer below? What is the benefit of this design? If I understand correctly, with the two tables that you said, I can to see the products sold with a single order. For example if in one order I sell 2 apples and 3 bananas, I will have one row in SalesHeader and two rows in the SalesLine, one with apples info, and another with the bananas info. In future i can see that in "this order" I sold 2 apples and 3 bananas, right?

Comment: @secon25 Yes to your first question, whenever a sale is made, that sale is recorded in the `SalesHeader` table and the details of that sales will be an individual line for each item in the `SalesLine` table. Generally the way this schema works is every time you make a new sale (even if it's exactly the same date as a previous sale) it gets new entries in the `SalesHeader` and`SalesLine` tables so you have the granularity of each sale but you can always `GROUP BY` the date later on to aggregate the quantities of all sales for a given date. For your second question, this is the *standard* for...

Comment: ...a system that deals with Sales. Microsoft (and I'm sure other database system companies) has an example database and this is the very schema design they use, and it's also commonplace among many ERP Systems. It gives you all the flexibility and granularity you would need to report off of it, in a [**normalized**](https://www.guru99.com/database-normalization.html) manner that helps reduce data redundancy and improve query efficiency.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answers!

Comment: @secon25 Absolutely, no problem!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with the semantic meaning of the SALES table. It looks like you expect it to contain one row that represents the **total sales** on a given day for a given product.

It seems to me like a better definition is for the SALES table to record individual sales during the day. Then it makes sense to extend it with the details of that sale, including the unit price of the product for that specific sale. You then will also want to extend the SALES table with some reference to the individual order, or customer reference or both. You also probably want to include the exact time of sale, either as a separate column, or (simpler) by making `saledate` into a full timestamp.